# Create gif from Servlett outputstream in Java

Tags: java, image, servlets, gif, outputstream

I am developing an application on a server to manage some Image showing stuff. Therefor I created a servlett to put an Image from a Directory into an outputstream so I can call it from my jsp to display the Image.

```
BufferedImage bi;
bi = ImageIO.read(new URL(imagePath));
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out);
out.close();
```

this part works fine. Now I thought it would be nice to get a Stream of Images and combine them to a .gif file and to show the .gif in my .jsp too.
In this Link http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/GifSequenceWriter.java
I found an example that should work(I hope so).
So I want to change this solution a little bit.I created another servlett where I do a for-loop on a hashmap and every time I want to pass the showimage the Id of the Image that I want.

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : mMap.entrySet()) 
{
 response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/showimage? 
 imageid="+entry.getValue());
}
```

After that, my showImage servlett stores the Image as .jpg in the outputstream. In the next step, within my for loop I want to get the image outputstream and use the writeSequence function.
Can anyone tell me how to get the image from the Outputstream? Or is the Outputstream sent straight back to client and this isn't even possible without copying the imageshow code in the new class?
Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for downvoating my question instead of telling me why it seems to be a bad question. I thought we are here to help eachother

Comment: You would need to convert each JPG into a GIF and then put them together with the GifSequenceWriter.  Each image in an animated GIF is still a GIF.